xymatrix arrow tips in tikzcd
I haver been using tikz-cd to write commutative diagrams for 3 years now, but I really like the default arrow style from xymatrix (figure below). I chose not to start using the latter because the syntax of the former is way simpler and intuitive. So I would like to know if it is possible to use the arrow tip style from xymatrix in tikz-cd.

A688701, Q728714.

You can get a similar arrow like this (fine tune the width and length as you like):
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  tikzcd to/.tip={cm to[width=2.5pt,length=4pt]}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
a \rar & b
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}



Nice solution. Thanks! Follow-up question: Is it possible to do apply those changes to the arrow from \to by redefining the command \to ?

@dwhydtea If you have a new question, use the ask question button on the top right and provide a compilable test document.
